# canvas5 creating Rectangle while erasing the object

Tags: html, canvas

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [unbind function in HTML5 Canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12564365/unbind-function-in-html5-canvas)

I have created a canvas where I am using rectangle, brush, and eraser. If I select brush then eraser it works fine but when I choose Reactangle then Eraser. It start creating reactangle in the brackground while erasing the object.

How can I unbind the context.rect(); function.

Please suggest.