# unbind function in HTML5 Canvas

Tags: html, html5-canvas

I want to unbind function in HTML5 Canvas...

Example: when I am selecting Brush after selecting option rectangle its creating Rectangle also when I am using brush. Please help me regarding same.

Thanks

Devesh

Comment: It is difficult to establish exactly what help you need here, is it possible to post some code?

Comment: Hi Neil, It would be really difficult to send the code here. pls drop a test mail on devrastogi@gmail.com and I will send you complete code there.

Comment: Maybe you can setup a jsfiddle.net, this is the standard way of isolating a piece of code that others can help you with on Stack.

Comment: Hi Neil THanks for your help... I have used js fiddle. Please check below url: http://jsfiddle.net/devrastogi/hGsDM/ First click on rectangle then use Erase option... You will see it will create another rectangle in the background....

Comment: Hi Neil, THanks for your help... but when i am not storing tools in array my color option is not working. Please check attached above links... and on created rectangle its showing black line or colored line starting from node x and y. Please suggest....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you are seeing another rectangle after selecting rectangle and then eraser is because of the following:

```
    function addClick(x, y, dragging) {
        clickX.push(x);
        clickY.push(y);
        clickDrag.push(dragging);
        hitColors.push(bgColor);
        clickTool.push(tool);
        toolSize.push(radius);
    }
```

You are adding every tool that is clicked to clickTool array. So once you add the rect then eraser, the rect is still there.

Then when you loop:

```
    function redraw() {
        context.width = canvas.width; // Clears the canvas
        context.lineJoin = "round";        

        for (var i = 0; i < clickX.length; i++) {
           // this will log rect then eraser over and over
           console.log(clickTool[i]);
        // ......
        }
    }
```

So you need to work out why you want to have an array of tools that have been selected, maybe you only need to have one at a time instead of holding on to them all.

Comment: Hi Neil, THanks for your help... but when i am not storing tools in array my color option is not working. Please check attached above links... and on created rectangle its showing black line or colored line starting from node x and y. Please suggest....